# Why all queries written in controller file instead of model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mysqli, eloquent

The eloquent queries like

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

is written in controller file. 
Why this not in model file. I am asking because models are meant for database operations.isn't it?

Comment: Why would you find a specific object and set data on it in your model? Your `Flight` model represents _all_ flights, not one specific flight.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I asked about all query codes are found in controller instead of model. Because in codeigniter the query codes is in view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from laravel documentation as to what is an eloquent model-

> Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.

What it means is that, a model file simply is the **class representation** of a table in the database.

For example `App\Flight` is a class corresponding to **Flights** table, hence you can write eloquent queries using the `Flight` class.

Relations between different tables are also defined in a model file.

Controller is the file where you actually **use** the models to query the database and write core logic. Think of controllers as acting as an intermediary between database and view.

Hope if clears the concept :)